# Kotlin error doesn't get catched inside WorkManager(?)

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, crash, android-workmanager

I have never encountered a similar situation like this...
I have a `RequestHelper` object that manages all requests. But in one instance, which emerged last week, the error handling just doesn't work. The location of the problem comes from the only `WorkManager` in the project (A hint?). Additionally, in the same update I've updated to SDK 34.

In Firebase Crashlytics this error shows up:

```
Fatal Exception: com.mike.standartstats.util.helpers.RequestHelper$ResponseCodeException:
       at com.mike.standartstats.util.helpers.RequestHelper$ResponseCodeException.<init>(RequestHelper.java:277)
       at com.mike.standartstats.util.helpers.RequestHelper.asyncRequest(RequestHelper.kt:146)
       at com.mike.standartstats.util.helpers.RequestHelper$request$1.invokeSuspend(RequestHelper.kt:93)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.java:584)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
```

It's very strange, that the error doesn't point to the class that inherits `WorkManager` or gives a location where the function in the `RequestHelper` got called.

Here are the relevant code lines from the `RequestHelper`:

```kotlin
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
fun request(
    context: Context,
    url: String,
    headers: Map<String, String>?,
    validate: (JSONObject) -> Unit,
    onException: (Exception) -> Unit,
    onFinished: (JSONObject) -> Unit
) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            val response = asyncRequest(context, url, headers, validate) // <- Error here

            if (context is Activity) {
                context.runOnUiThread {
                    onFinished(response)
                }
            } else {
                onFinished(response)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) { // <- Why doesn't it get catched?
            if (context is Activity) {
                context.runOnUiThread {
                    onException(e)
                }
            } else {
                onException(e)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun asyncRequest(
    context: Context?,
    url: String,
    headers: Map<String, String>?,
    validate: (JSONObject) -> Unit
): JSONObject {
    var clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    /* ... */
    val client = clientBuilder.build()

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url)
    /* ... */

    val response = client.newCall(request.build()).execute()
    if (response.code !in 200..299) {
        if (response.code == 429) throw APILimitReached()
        else throw ResponseCodeException(response.code) // <- Exception gets thrown here
    }

    val responseJson = JSONObject(response.body?.string() ?: "")

    response.close()

    validate(responseJson)
    return responseJson
}

// Custom exception defined here
class ResponseCodeException(val responseCode: Int, val error: String? = null): Exception()
```

I've suspected that the async function is the reason (But that wouldn't make sense because it only crashes in the `WorkManager`) so I tried using `Thread {}.start()` instead of `GlobalScope.launch {}` but that didn't work. Additionally, I've looked at every other try catch that could cause an issue: Without success.

I'm really out of ideas (despite 8 years of experience )...

Comment: Is there a reason you are using GlobalScope.launch and not another way?

Comment: Not really. It's just my favourite way to make async stuff. Do you think this is the issue?

Comment: Using GlobalScope can lead to memory leaks and other scenarios. I would suggest reading up on replacements [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/).

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at it. Could this be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Without having more information on the crash, it's hard to say. It could be.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have more information. It's really suspicious that the Crashlytics report is so truncated.